# Bootstrap CSS: Columns Pushed To Next Line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, row

I use the following code to create three-column rows:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Column [1] -->
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <h4>Four or Five Title Words</h4>
      <img src="a-thumbnail.jpg">
      <span>A short description</span>
    </div>

    <!-- Column [2] -->
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <h4>Four or Five Title Words</h4>
      <img src="a-thumbnail.jpg">
      <span>A short description</span>
    </div>

    <!-- Column [3] -->
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <h4>Four or Five Title Words</h4>
      <img src="a-thumbnail.jpg">
      <span>A short description</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">...</div>
  <div class="row">...</div>
  <div class="row">...</div>
</div>
```

Here is the straightforward desired result: *n* rows of  three columns each

```
[1][2][3]
[1][2][3]
[1][2][3]
[1][2][3]
[1][2][3]
```

Some rows display fine, but others have one or more columns pushed to the next row at the large and medium break points, like so:

```
[1][2][3]
[1][2][3]
   [1][2]
      [3]
[1][2][3]
[1][2][3]
      [1]
   [2][3]
[1][2][3]
```

Notice that these are right aligned as well. The image in each div is very small, so size doesn't appear to be a factor. There really isn't much text either, just a few words. The content in each div is fairly similar to all the others.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to troubleshoot or resolve? Thanks.

Comment: which bootstrap version are you using

Comment: Sidenote: You don't need to specify all screen sizes in classes. using `col-md-4 col-xs-12` Would yeild the same results. If you want to be more verbose that's fine, I just wanted to make sure you knew.

Comment: It might be because you are not using `img-responsive` on your image. See if [this](https://codepen.io/codearts/pen/Evvaxb) answer your question

Comment: Using V3. I haven't tried img-responsive, but those thumbnails are tiny. For what it's worth, the same thing happens if I try it with 4 columns (e.g., col-lg-3).

Comment: Have you applied any external css of your own? I wasn't able to replicate the behavior you mentioned with the snippet you provided.